# Why does special characters in my variable disappear on doing an lindex in TCL?

Tags: list, tcl

I have a list in my application that i work on.. Its basically like this:

```
$item = {text1 text2 text3}
```

Then I pick up the first member in the list with:

```
lindex $item 0
```

On doing this text1 which used to be (say) `abcdef\12345`  becomes `abcdef12345`.
But its very important for me to not lose this `\` . Why  is it disappearing. THere are other characters like `-` and `>` which don't disappear.  Please note that I cannot escape the `\` in the text beforehand. If there's anything I can do before operating on the `$item` with `lindex`, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\` is a Tcl list metasyntax character, unlike `-`, `>` or any alphanumeric. You need to convert your string into a proper Tcl list before using `lindex` (or any other list-consuming operation) on it. To do that, you need to understand *exactly* what *you* mean by “words” in your input data. If your input data is a sequences of non-whitespace characters separated by single whitespace characters, you can use `split` to do the conversion to a list:

```
set properList [split $item]
# Now we can use it...
set theFirstWord [lindex $properList 0]
```

If you've got a different separator, `split` takes an optional extra character to say what to split by. *For example,* to split by colons (`:`) you do:

```
set properList [split $item ":"]
```

However, if you have other sorts of splitting rules, this doesn't work so well. For example, if you can split by *multiple* whitespace characters, it's actually better to use `regexp` (with the `-all -inline` options) to do the word-identification:

```
# Strictly, this *chooses* all sequences of one or more non-whitespace characters
set properList [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $item]
```

You can also do splitting by multi-character sequences, though in that case it is most easily done by mapping (with `string map`) the multi-character sequence to a single rare character first. Unicode means that there are *lots* of such characters to pick…

```
# NUL, \u0000, is a great character to pick for text, and terrible for binary data
# For binary data, choose something beyond \u00ff
set properList [split [string map {"BOUNDARY" "\u0000"} $item] "\u0000"]
```

Even more complex options are possible, but that's when you use `splitx` from [Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html).

```
package require textutil::split

# Regular expression to describe the separator; very sophisticated approach
set properList [textutil::split::splitx $item {SPL+I*T}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In tcl Lists can be created in several ways:

by setting a variable to be a list of values

```
set lst {{item 1} {item 2} {item 3}}
```

with the split command

```
set lst [split "item 1.item 2.item 3" "."]
```

with the list command.

```
set lst [list "item 1" "item 2" "item 3"]
```

And an individual list member can be accessed with the lindex command.

```
set x "a b c"
puts "Item 2 of the list {$x} is: [lindex $x 2]\n"
```

This will give output:

```
Item 2 of the list {a b c} is: c
```

And With respect to the question asked
You need to define the variable like this `abcdef\\12345`

In order to make this clear try to run the following command.

```
puts "\nI gave $100.00 to my daughter."
```

and

```
puts "\nI gave \$100.00 to my daughter."
```

The second one will give you the proper result.

If you don't have the option to change the text, try to save the text in curly braces, as mentioned in the first example.

```
set x {abcd\12345}
puts "A simple substitution: $x\n"
```

Output:

```
A simple substitution: abcd\12345

set y [set x {abcdef\12345}]
```

And check for this output:

```
puts "Remember that set returns the new value of the variable: X: $x Y: $y\n"
```

Output:

```
Remember that set returns the new value of the variable: X: abcdef\12345 Y: abcdef\12345
```

Comment: Well thanks for the info. But my question is different.

Comment: Sorry Somehow my network got disconnected, Couldn't give the complete answer. Please find the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, but I do not have the option to escape the "\" in the list variable. In the application that i work with the user selects some text which is in the form of a list. Hence i have no control on the contents of the list that is given and cannot modify it.